# Open a chrome tab from delayed javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

When I window.open("http://blarg") in chrome, I get a new tab.  If I delay the open, say using a jquery `$(hrm).animate({},5e3,function(){window.open(url));` it opens the url in a new window with no status bar, etc — if I give it permission to pop-up that is.

I'm looking for a way to get the instant behavior, that is, I wish to open a URL after an animation, but still in a new tab.

I imagine I could get by with learning a way to instruct chrome to never ever open pop-ups and to always open them in tabs (I imagine there's a webkit setting, why it's not a built in is a mystery); but I'd rather try to find a way to do it from the javascript if possible.

I somewhat doubt there's any way to do this though.  I'm not aware of any javascript that's tab-aware.

Comment: Do you really need to open a new window? http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808419/creating-new-tab-switching-between-tabs-in-firefox/) was asked about tabs in Firefox, but the same answer applies:

> [There is no way to force a window to open as a tab. It's all dependent on the user's preference settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808419/creating-new-tab-switching-between-tabs-in-firefox/1808432#1808432).